# Что неправильно при вызове EnumWindows ? Ошибка: Невозможно упаковать "return value"

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Хочу пройтись по всем открытым формам и заполнить List < WindowData > _WndList. Как это можно сделать? Я так понимаю, проблема в передаче управляемого типа в неуправляемый код? Но вроде **GCHandlе** позволяет...

```
static public class PInvoke
{       
     //--http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.EnumWindows
    private delegate bool EnumWindowsProc(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern int EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc callPtr, IntPtr lParam);

    public class WindowsEnum
    {
        private static EnumWindowsProc cb;

        public static void FillWindowsEnum()
        {
            List<WindowData> WndList = new List<WindowData>(); //здесь будем хранить наши формы
            GCHandle gch = GCHandle.Alloc(WndList); 
            cb = new EnumWindowsProc(EnumProc);

            IntPtr loc = GCHandle.ToIntPtr(gch);

            int ret = EnumWindows(cb, loc); //вот здесь выдает exeption

            gch = GCHandle.FromIntPtr(loc);
            //loc.Free();                   
        }

        private static bool EnumProc(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam)
         {
            GCHandle gch = GCHandle.FromIntPtr(lParam);
            List<WindowData> _WndList = (List<WindowData>)gch.Target;
            WindowData data = new WindowData();

            // fill list
             StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(256);
             int ret = GetClassName(hWnd, sb, sb.Capacity); //WinApi функция
             if (ret != 0)
                 data.Wndclass = sb.ToString();

             sb.Clear();
             ret = GetWindowText(hWnd, sb, sb.Capacity);  //WinApi функция               
             data.hWnd = hWnd;

             _WndList.Add(data);
             return true; 
         }
    }               
 }    

....

class FormAssistent
{
  ...
    private void Initialize()
    {   
        PInvoke.WindowsEnum.FillWindowsEnum();
    }

  //класс для хранения данных одной формы
  public class WindowData
  {
    public string Wndclass;  //имя класса окна
    public string Title;    
    public IntPtr hWnd;      //хендл окна

  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так текст Exception сам за себя говорит в чем проблема. Используйте `EnumWindows` либо так:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc callPtr, IntPtr lParam);
```

Либо так:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern int EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc callPtr, IntPtr lParam);
```

Судя по тексту Exception'a лучше использовать так, что бы не возникало подобных ситуаций:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
private static extern int EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc callPtr, IntPtr lParam);
```

P.S. По ссылке в Ваших комментариях это указано :)

Answer (score 0):

Я неправильно указал способ преобразования возвращаемого значения из unmanaged code to managed:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshalasattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396